# How to show ScalePrecision error message at asp-validation-for?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have this FluentValidation rule in C#

```
public class InputDepositViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<InputDepositViewModel>
{
    public InputDepositViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(reg => reg.DepositAmount).NotNull().ScalePrecision(2, 2);
    }
}
```

And when I run to test it, it did return the error but the error return back to the browser is json format error message `{"DepositAmount":["'Deposit Amount' must not be more than 2 digits in total, with allowance for 2 decimals. 1 digits and 3 decimals were found."]}`. How do I get the error message to be displayed at `<span asp-validation-for="DepositAmount" class="text-danger"></span>`?

If I leave it as blank, it did return the error `'Deposit Amount' must not be empty.` to `<span asp-validation-for="DepositAmount" class="text-danger"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

`ScalePrecision` [is not supported out of the box for client side validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#clientside-validation). You have to write your own client side validator and associated javascript hook. This [guide](https://ml-software.ch/posts/extending-client-side-validation-with-fluentvalidation-and-jquery-unobtrusive-in-an-asp-net-core-application) covers it step by step, I've used it to create my own in the past.